# How to change component in react JS without using navigator?

Tags: mobile, reactjs, native

I'm a newbie for React Native and I don't have native development experience(I only worked on several hybrid apps), while learning this react native framework, I get several questions which block my learning.

1. How to navigate from one page(component) to another page(component) without relying on navigatorIOS or navigator component? In Hybrid develop mode, it's so easy, just add element A with href attribute would work, but in React Native, how to do it? I read some examples, they all use navigator or navigateIOS component to do it.
2. Is there any interceptor mechanism in react native so that we could inject some logic before rendering or loading component, for example, we want to have interceptor to check whether user has been login?
3. How to save data globally (cross components)? In Hybrid mode, we have session, we have local storage, and if we angular JS framework, we could use Service or root Scope to save data, by using react native, how do we save data cross components?

Since I'm new to react native and new to native application development, these questions might be fairly stupid, if anyone could help on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know i'm answering to your question but please check this router component for react 
   https://github.com/rackt/react-router
2. ComponentWillMount and ComponentDidMount can be used to perform some initial loading
3. You can use flux framework along with React which can do almost all like in angular js

https://facebook.github.io/flux/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  For the first question, seems react-router is for react web, not react native, right?  For the second question, ComponentWillMount is not the interceptor I'm asking for, if we want to intercept all the component, we have to implement ComponentWilrlMount function for each Component class, by using Interceptor, we could then put logic in Interceptor only once.  For the last question, seems flux is also for react web, not react native, right?